# Firebase not sending SMS Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, sms, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I'm creating an app for Android phones and using Firebase OTP authentication but I'm not sure if the codes are wrong or there's really an issue with Firebase sending SMS as what I've read as I have searched so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btSendCode;
Button btResend;
Button btVerify;

EditText etPhoneNumber;
EditText etEnterCode;

TextView tvGoHere;

String phoneVerificationID;
FirebaseAuth auth;
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks verificationCallbacks;
PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken resendToken;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btSendCode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sendcode);
    btResend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_resend);
    btVerify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_verify);

    etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_phonenumber);
    etEnterCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_entercode);

    tvGoHere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_gohere);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void clickSendCode(View view) {
    etPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btSendCode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    etEnterCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btResend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btVerify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //firebase code
    String phoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

    setUpVerificationCallbacks();

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,
            120,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            verificationCallbacks
    );

}

public void setUpVerificationCallbacks() {
    verificationCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            if(e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid phone format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if(e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Too many requests", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationID, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

            phoneVerificationID = verificationID;
            resendToken = token;
        }
    };
}

public void clickVerifyCode(View view) {
    String code = etEnterCode.getText().toString();

    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(phoneVerificationID, code);
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

public void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                    } else {
                        if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

public void clickResendCode(View view) {
    String phoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

    setUpVerificationCallbacks();

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,
            120,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            verificationCallbacks,
            resendToken
    );
}

public void onClickGoHere(View view) {
    Intent intentLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentLogin);
}
}
```

Comment: did u read the docs and follow the steps..

Comment: Yes. Been watching YouTube tutorials as well. @PeterHaddad

Comment: u need to use a physical device. and set your app's SHA-1 hash

Comment: Do you mean that I need to use a real phone to run the app instead of an emulator? @PeterHaddad yes SHA-1 has already been set too

Comment: Yes!  it won't work with an emulator..As stated in the docs: Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Maybe that's why it's not working. Okay I will try and let you know. Thank you!!! @PeterHaddad

Comment: yes most probably, no problem! You should really read the docs to avoid waiting an hour to see what the problem is

Comment: Hi @PeterHaddad my firebase is now sending sms! Thanks a lot! :)))

Comment: @JonnahParis how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @RatilalChopda, the codes I have are working fine. I was just using an emulator instead of a real Android device that's why it was not sending SMS.

Comment: @JonnahParis Thank you for your explanation. enjoy Happy coding.

Comment: @JonnahParis no problem! that's great :)) Read this also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, to know how to ask questions for the future

Answer (score 1):

Phone number must begin with `+`, followed by country code and followed by number. Example: `+9195021*****`. And enable  phone authentication sign method .